# how to make associative array using loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
//response = [{"id":"1","created":"26-05-2016"},{"id":"2","created":"25-05-2016"},{"id":"8","created":"21-05-2016"}]

success : function(response){
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

// here i want to make associative array... like `array['user'] = id` & `array['created']`..

please help me

Comment: Your code should have already achieved it.

Comment: For example, to get "created" in id "1", use `obj[0]["created"]`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply try this

```js
    var response = [{"id":"1","created":"26-05-2016"},{"id":"2","created":"25-05-2016"},{"id":"8","created":"21-05-2016"}];
    var output = response.map(function(obj){ return { user: obj.id, created: obj.created } })
    
    console.log(output)
```

Comment: @MuhammadWakeel try the demo